# Stop agents moving randomly from node to another node in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent, pickup

we are sending people (agent) from one node to another with "Move to" blocks and want them to be picked up by taxis (agent). In principle, the pick-up works, but some of the people are leaving the node randomly without reason or order.

Screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Jaq.png)

We checked if there are wrong "Move to"s
We tried every option in the queue and the pick-up block.

It would be great if anyone of you is able to support us with a simple solution, as we are not able to program Java.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Agents only use nodes as approximations. Nodes cannot be "full" of agents, agents cannot "occupy" nodes, etc.

Nodes are just a simple support tool for quick animations. An approximation. You can have 1 million agents on 1 tiny node... Neither the node nor the agents will care.

Either you can live with this or you toggle your agents into actual pedestrians using physical spaces. (But even then, you do not have 100% control about their detailed movements and they may overrun a "node").

If you need to have 100% control, you'd need to "agentify" your nodes as well. I created a [full tutorial](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGJP0k1miFbQ0XfchiMK9nxj-qr42dyw) but it is very Java-heavy and not for the faint-hearted :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the control logic between the taxi and the people but from your control logic block there is no control between the queue and moveTo so the people will move to without order.Maybe you need to add a delay block or hold block before moveTo. You can learn more about the pick up block from the example model 'JobShop'